# What is the meaning of words 'stochastic', 'temporal' in computer graphics?

Tags: terminology

Last time I see a lot of papers which operates on this words, i.e. *stochastic AA*, *temporal coherence* etc. What does that means? Can you provide examples with explanations in plain English?

Comment: I did post an answer, but i don't think looking up Wiktionary/wikipedia for you is a good use of this sites resources. Anyway you may wish to refine your question or we can wait for community opinion. Setting boundaries for what is and what is not in scope, is still valuable for the community.

Comment: @joojaa I've added a [meta post](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/133/should-we-allow-word-definition-questions) so people can discuss whether word definitions should be on topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its something you should be able to google in 60 seconds.

Comment: The answers answer to what you asked. The time is one :) How to get info from previous frames is a different question (you can reconstruct infos, store them in a buffer etc. etc.). Sthocastic and random are basically synonyms, often you use sthocastic to describe a process and random to describe a variable.

Comment: I think you should ask the question that you want to know. Like i sad its very clear what the words mean but the implementation of those things is a different story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A stochastic process is one where you gather your samples randomly. So stochastic AA is antialiasing where you gather multiple samples for the same pixel with small random changes.
- Temporal refers to a process over time. Temporal coherence is for instance mentioned when you have no flickering artifacts, or aliasing that you see during movement. It means that frames are coherent in a certain time window.

Answer (score 7):

- Stochastic = Random. Stochastic AA, Anti-aliasing technique based on randomized sample distribution (as opposed to fixed sample pattern).

  Also see: [Monte Carlo Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)
- Temporal = depends on time. Temporal coherence, how consistent X is over time.

  Typically you hear of temporal aliasing, temporal artefacts etc.